# Where is all my RAM going? 60% used, but by what?

Tags: memory

I have 8GB RAM in my system, but even on very low loads, over 60% of it is used. This causes my PC to slow down when i for example run Visual Studio together with Chrome.

[image: PC specs]

[image: Running processes]

Comment: Post the Memory information from the Task Manager Performance tab. Add the output from RAMMap https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/rammap if possible. You are just asking for guesses with what you have posted.

Comment: Most likely this memory is used by the file cache and is discarded when memory is required. You cannot see it in the task list. This is not the reason for your slow-downs,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the cause and disadvantages of high memory usage as time passes on Windows 8.1?](https://superuser.com/questions/748679/what-is-the-cause-and-disadvantages-of-high-memory-usage-as-time-passes-on-windo)