# Insane Sudden Memory Usage on Windows 8.1

Tags: memory, windows-8.1, task-manager

When booting Windows 8.1 my memory usage is about 1,7 GB. Then after some time - less than a minute - it jumps up to around 6 GB. Task Manager does not show anything that would use up that much.

Everything is fine with the memory because on Ubuntu everything is as it should be.

I guess that the problem appeared after the latest update I did. I am not sure though.

Any ideas?

Comment: post pictures of RAMMap: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Comment: FYI, a good OS should use as much memory as possible.

Comment: Additionally does this happen in minimal configuration?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here is the [RAMMap](http://i.imgur.com/WV8exJH.png). The nonpaged pool is quite suspicious.

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean with **minimal configuration**?

Comment: Windows 8.X supports selecting a "minimal" boot configuration.  This is often helpful to determine which application is slowing the startup routine

Comment: the nonpaged pool is too high. I explained here how to trace it: http://superuser.com/a/674725/174557

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows using too much RAM, how to diagnose resource hog](http://superuser.com/questions/674649/windows-using-too-much-ram-how-to-diagnose-resource-hog)

Answer (score 1):

You can also run **perfmon** tests and examine the detailed report that will be produced.

In order to run perfmon and get the report, open Powershell as an administrator and type:

**perfmon /report**

This will produce a report that it can be also saved as an .XML file and it opens with any browser.

Comment: **perfmon /report** gives an error and says that the operator or admin refused the request. Opening **perfmon** without the report gives me an [error](http://i.imgur.com/8lltxYj.png). This dialog shows up twice. The report afterwards seems lacking, showing only some information about the CPU usage.

Answer (score -2):

Use Poolmon.exe to find which pool tag is the cause:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2012/08/30/troubleshooting-pool-leaks-part-2-poolmon.aspx

> Often when we are collecting data for a poor performance scenario there are two pieces of data that we collect.  Perfmon log data is one...  The other piece of data is poolmon logs.  The memory manager tracks pool usage according to the tag associated with the pool allocations, using a technique called pool tagging.  Poolmon gathers this data and displays it in an easy to use format.  Poolmon can also be configured to dump data to a log, and in some scenarios it is beneficial to schedule poolmon to periodically collect such logs.  There are several available techniques to schedule poolmon...

Often caused by drivers.

Comment: "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."