# Persistent massive non-paged pool

Tags: memory, windows-8.1, memory-leaks

Right, I've had to [do this](http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/windows-8-338/awareness-thread-windows-8-memory-leak-ndu-sys-4309046.html) to remove a memory leak problem from the LAN driver + windows 8.1 which showed itself when I download things from steam.

Now I have played Alien: Isolation and had a very similar problem: the RAM usage sky-rockets and I have to quit before the PC becomes unusable. **Even if I restart** the non-paged pool remains at 4.3GB and so my usage remains at ~73%.

Firstly, how do I "reset" the non-paged pool?

Lastly, what is going on here?

This is a new build (http://uk.pcpartpicker.com/user/lucidnonsense/saved/YPddnQ)

Memory stuff (after a restart):

```
8.0 GB DDR3

Speed:  1333 MHz
Slots used: 2 of 4
Form factor:    DIMM
Hardware reserved:  139 MB

Available   1.9 GB
Cached  618 MB
Committed   6.5/9.7 GB
Paged pool  175 MB
Non-paged pool  4.3 GB
In use  5.8 GB
```

[DXDIAG stuff](http://pastebin.com/XYUrdBnv) (notice all the RADAR_PRE_LEAK_WOW64 problems in the diagnostics below)

Edit: also the memory diagnostics tool turns up nothing though it does reset the memory

[image: task manager screenshot]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows using too much RAM, how to diagnose resource hog](http://superuser.com/questions/674649/windows-using-too-much-ram-how-to-diagnose-resource-hog)

Comment: I posted all required steps here, to debug this issue: http://superuser.com/a/674725/174557

Comment: Right I've tested this method and I can now do it. But the problem has failed to turn up again so I'll just do this when it does. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please take a look at the following.
There is explained how you can identify what is causing your **memory leak**.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560135(v=vs.85).aspx