# Multiple random BSODs

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, bsod, cmd.exe, dump

I've been getting different BSODs lately. The most recent, last night was while I was playing Fallout 4, my PC got hung up and gave me a system_service_exception (win32k.sys). I checked event viewer and its says "Kernal power". I see some logged info, but I'm not sure what's used to troubleshoot; what info should I link to in this post?

I've also gotten a system_store_exception and a whea_uncorrectable_error, among others. I started in the cmd.exe and ran a chkdsk on my OS drive, HDD and a laptop HDD that I have installed in a hotswap bay. All that came up was 20 bad files on the laptop drive. I did a chkdsk r/ on it and it seemed to come back fine. I also ran an SFC.exe /scannow, even though I don't really know what it scans for and that came back fine. I'm going to try to make a kernal dump file from the crash I found in the event viewer.

I also ran the Windows memory diagnostic tool and then my computer restarted and I don't know where to find the results. Is this also different from the memtest86 I keep seeing?

The rate that I see these errors is random. Sometimes just waking my computer will bring a BSOD, 2 times when I would get into a LoL match, last night in Fallout. Oh, also, Fallout will just crash? Like, I don't get a prompt or an error. I'll open the game and mostly before I can even load a game, the app will just kill itself.

I'm using Windows 10, an FX-8350, r9 280, 8 gigs of ripjaws and the aforementioned drives. I've updated my bios, GPU, CPU, mobo drivers, steam is up to date. Is there somewhere in the Device Manager where I can see the active driver to make sure I installed it correcctly? Any suggestions are appreciated. I'm taking this as a learning opportunity since I am semi-new to PC/Windows troubleshooting.

Edit: So I finished a short run of memtest86; about an hour and a half and got through one whole pass and 50% of another. I've read that it should run longer, so ill probably turn it on tonight before I go to bed. Anyway, that memtest finished with no errors. But, I let my computer go to sleep so I could grab some food and I just got back. I wake it, and boom, Critical_Process_Died. I suppose ill try to grab a fresh dump file. Just have to find it.

Edit 2: So I ran Memtest86 (Ver. 6.2.0) for 9h 31m and then it froze, right in front of my eyes. For the 2 hours before that, it was crawling; while on test 13 (hammer test) the timer was rising in increments of 2-3 sec. Is this a particularly stressful test? It was also only using 1 of my  "8" cores. I then went to the bios and decided to hit F5 and put everything at default settings in case I had changed anything in the past that I forgot about. I am guessing that this must mean I have a hardware issue because memtest86 runs outside of Windows.

These are the last 3 bugchecks. I'm using WhoCrashed(v5.51) because I can not for the life of me get the .dmp files to open in WinDBG or VS. The first 2 are from the crash during Memtest86 and the 3rd is from the Crash while playing Fallout 4.
[Bugcheck with WhoCrashed(v5.51)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1XlL.png)

Comment: Unless this started after some windows update installed a bad driver, I would begin to suspect a thermal or power issue, faulty motherboard/CPU, or faulty drive.  There is not one "active driver".  Video drivers are off the list of things that make the kernel panic. But that leaves chipset, SATA device drivers, and about a dozen other core windows drivers that can panic if bad. If updating to latest doesn't work, try restoring to a previous known working good configuration. Sadly microsoft made doing that almost impossible now in Windows 8 and Windows 10. I'd put a new drive and reinstall.

Comment: The Windows memory diagnostic tool is very different from memtest86. Memtest86 is much better. Get it and run it; I suspect you have bad RAM.

Comment: I did unseat a RAM stick, while I was tinkering around one night, just to check if it was dusty. I can try to reseat it and maybe even run my system with 1 (of the 2 sticks) to see if the problems persist.

Comment: Could you post some links to download the .dmp files? We could then use WinDBG to get more detailed information on the BSOD to try and locate the culprit.

Comment: Random bsod's are almost always bad ram.

Comment: share the dmp files from C:\Windows\minidump

Comment: If memtest is failing, then you have bad memory, start with a single module still you introduce the problem module.  Even if memtest was a high usage program ( it isn't ) that doesn't mean much, a CPU is designed to be at 100% load, if that is a problem then you still have a hardware problem.

Comment: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION "This error has been linked to excessive paged pool usage and may occur due to user-mode graphics drivers crossing over and passing bad data to the kernel code." (from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ( http://superuser.com/questions/859397/persistent-massive-non-paged-pool )

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I did two things and I haven't gotten a BSOD upon wake up or mid-game, in almost 12 hours of use, which is great. I understand that only one variable should be changed at a time to understand what actually fixed the problem, but I really don't want to recreate the problem on my most prized possession.

I re-seated both RAM sticks and I removed my (probably malware infested) 2.5" laptop SSD from my hot-swap bay. Like I said, I've gone a lot longer without a problem than I have been the last few days. I wouldn't be surprised if it was my 2.5" drive, but as much input as I've seen about RAM, it was probably just a bad seat.

Cheers.