# ReadyBoost memory leaks on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory-leaks, readyboost

I seem to have a very bad memory leak and I have no idea why. It gets real bad even with only a few programs running with 12GB of RAM.

Here's what poolmen.exe gave me, as you can see, there is a program that uses A LOT of memory:
[image: Poolmon diagnostic]

I found the culprit, rdyboost.sys that seems to be ReadyBoost byt of course.. Microsoft:

[image: Faulty driver]

I googled it, but cannot find a solution, only a post from a guy contacting Microsoft support, to which they sent a generic stupid answer, then stopped answering:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/rdyboostsys-causing-memory-leaks-on-windows-10/e133821d-d9ef-4ecd-959f-1537b79c955b

Anybody has any ideas how to get rid of that problem?

**I have Windows 10 installed on an SSD by the way, I know ReadyBoost is used with flash drives, so I don't know if the problem is linked to that since SSD is flash memory**

Comment: how log does it take to see the leak? If you can see some grow in under 1-2 minutes, use xperf to capture the usage: http://superuser.com/a/674725/174557 (use the Win10 WPT from the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Comment: any status update? can you trace the grow with xperf?

Comment: any update? If not, I vote to close it, because we can't help you

Comment: the smR0 tag is the cause. run the findstr. command. Until you reply, I voted to close as too broad