# Possible Memory Leak in rdbss.sys (Native Component)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, memory-leaks

OS: Windows 10 Pro (10.0.10586)
Proc: i5-4590
RAM: 16 GB

[image: Relevant Data]

I've noticed that my memory usage is climbing out of control in comparison to what I have open and what Process Explorer is showing for individual processes.

Sysinternals' RAMMap shows that 7 GB of my 16 GB total is "Driver Locked"

Referencing instructions in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/674649/windows-using-too-much-ram-how-to-diagnose-resource-hog), I used poolmap to get an idea of what's going on.

The results are... interesting, as rdbss.sys appears to be using 2.2k Petabytes of data.

Am I reading my results wrong or does the [Redirected Drive Buffering SubSystem Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556810(v=vs.85).aspx) have a serious problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite my weird findings in poolmon, this was actually a result of me forgetting I had 6 Virtual Machines in Hyper-V that were set to resume on host restart.