# Can anyone explain these poolmon numbers?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, memory-management, smb2

This screenshot is from a machine which I believe might have a driver memory leak so I've been monitoring poolmon.exe.  This is not the issue I am chasing but the numbers for LS2i are so absurd I was wondering if someone could explain them?  findstr suggests LS2i is owned by svr2.sys which is Smb 2.0 Server driver.
[image: poolmon.exe screeshot]
Please note the question is about the absurd numbers reported for LS2i in the screenshot NOT about finding the real memory hog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows using too much RAM, how to diagnose resource hog](http://superuser.com/questions/674649/windows-using-too-much-ram-how-to-diagnose-resource-hog)

Comment: follow the duplicate link and use xperf/WPA to capture some allocations of the pool usage grow and analyze it. For WIn10, use the Win10 SDK: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk