# Windows takes too much RAM on startup

Tags: windows, boot, memory

I disabled everything in autostart - and still. I will be happy uninstall something, but I can't find the exact cause. I want my 1-2 gb back. If its important - I am on Lenovo G710.

Here is task manager and poolmon screenshots

[image]
[image]

Comment: The Task Manager screenshot is useless. Please provide a screenshot of the Performance → Memory view.

Comment: We need more information.  How much system memory do you have, I am lazy, spell it out specifically for us.   How much memory is being used?  Is the memory usage just high when the system is started or does it remain high?  Unused memory is useless, so if it remains high, have you recieved an actual warning that you have ran out of **physical** memory?  I have notice lots of people wan their system not to use memory, yet when you do acomplish that, the system ends up being actually slower due to the configuration changes you performed.

Comment: @Ramhound, Windows doesn't have a warning for "out of physical memory". The pop-up you're thinking of is for commit charge approaching commit limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CM31 tag is used when a registry hives are loaded/read at boot when Windows is  loading your userprofile.

[image]

This can't be really optimized.

The `Thre` Tag is `Thread`, so applications run a lot of Threads. [Follow my guide and use xperf/WPA](https://superuser.com/a/674725/174557) to find out which process is causing this.

In my demo is is caused by GData Antivirus:

[image]

In WPA, also look for the cause of the `Se` (General security allocations) and `PROC` (Process objects).

Comment: Further: the registry is loaded into _paged_ pool, so the CM31 tags don't represent a permanent "usage" of RAM.

Comment: it only means it could be paged out, but doesn't mean it will be done

Comment: It will be if there's memory pressure for something else. An enormous amount of data is faulted in from the registry at boot time and never looked at again, so it's a prime candidate for repurposing. perfmon has a counter that shows you how much of the paged pool is actually paged in (memory object, "paged pool resident bytes").

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, forgot about this post. I resolved this by windows update. Its weird, since it was almost up to date. Also deinstalled McAffee antivirus, could also be the case. Thanks for the guide.