# 8gb RAM usage almost 100% with nothing running

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, ramdisk, memory-usage

I've a problem recently with my PC.
The RAM usage is always almost 100% no matter how many apps it's running.
The problem appears these days and before nothing was wrong.

I'm using windows 10, my ram is the HyperX 8 GB 2133 MHz DDR4 (HX421C14FB/8) and my MOBO is the MSI Gaming M3 (MS-7978).

Task manager screenshots while only google chrome (to write this question) was open but it's the same when there is no app running:

[image: Task1]

[image: Task2]

[image: Task3]

Comment: Your problem is the nonpaged pool usage. This is usually due to a buggy device driver. See magicandre1981's fine answer to see how to diagnose it here: http://superuser.com/a/674725/348119  Do post the screenshot of poolmon , and also post your etl file on a file sharing service so others can help (MA's answer explains how to use WPR to get the etl file).

Comment: Looks like you have Killer Network Management installed. It has a reputation for memory leaks

Comment: Can you show the "details" tab in the task manager?

Comment: The "details" tab in Task Manager won't often help with pool leaks.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is the non-paged pool, usually caused by a driver issue. Typically it would be less than the paged pool.

Comment: Oh, ok. What should I do?

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: @LMiller7 - Be specific.  The process to diagnose a buggy driver is not exactly simple.  Your answer should explain the entire process.  If there is an existing question, with an answer, then this question should be flagged as duplicate.  This answer as currently written does provide enough information to answer the author's question.