# Windows 10 - How can I figure out which software is allocating how much RAM

Tags: windows-10, memory, task-manager

In the task manager under the "performance" tab it says that 24,7 GB of my 32 GB are in use.

So I tried to figure out, what is using all this RAM. On the tab "user" it says only 2.9 GB is used:

[image]

And if you look under the "Details" tab and summarise all the used RAM values, then you don't get even close to 24,7 GB.

Why does it say that 79% of my RAM is in use?

[image]

The only explanation I can guess is, that some software is allocating alot of RAM. How to figure out which software is allocating how much RAM

---

**RamMap**:

[image]

**RamMap - after closing Virtual Box**

[image]

Comment: Why are you worried about this? Is the value rapidly increasing, or do you just feel vaguely uncomfortable because you think more of your RAM should always be empty? See https://superuser.com/questions/674649/windows-using-too-much-ram-how-to-diagnose-resource-hog?rq=1

Comment: You have at least one VM running. How much memory did you assign? You're also running known extreme memory hogs (Chrome, Teams, Spotify). Keep in mind that memory accounting is truly difficult, because of shared memory and whatnot.

Comment: You can enable additional columns for the details view. If it is a corporate machine keep in mind that you might not be seeing all processes from all users.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Im need to know how much RAM the various softwares are allocating, because some programs start to be very slow (e.g. HeidiSQL) because I almost reach the maximum amount of available RAM. I need this information to evaluate if I can shutdown some unneeded programs. The VM is allocating 16 GB.

Comment: Windows uses as much memory as it can. It will try to use all but 256k. You are looking at private bytes. This is memory usage of a program **minus** Windows' libraries. According to your Task Manager  Windows can't find anything to do with 1.7 GB of memory. You are not memory stressed.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the first tab "Use Counts" of RAMMap - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/rammap

Comment: @HelpingHand, Interessting software, I added a screenshot.

Comment: @user1644677 I'm sorry but that's simply not true. Windows does not *use as much memory as it can*. From the screenshots it also is clearly visible that this isn't about cache or buffers, which is what you were probably referring to. Also, it definitely is true that the system slows down if it doesn't have enough breathing room. Though the *~6 GiB* that are *available* should indeed be enough.

Comment: Looks like the problem here is too many page table entries.

Comment: Driver Locked is Probably VirtualBox. Do you have a VM running when you ran RAMMap?

Comment: @HelpingHand, yes, the VM was running

Comment: So stopping any running VMs and refreshing RAMMap will presumably release the Driver Locked memory.

Comment: I added a screenshot, after I closed the virtual box machine.